# Ubuntu 16.04.1 Post Upgrade - Not detecting hardware

Tags: drivers, 16.04, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, amd-graphics

After poking at this nearly all day I have determined that for whatever reason Ubuntu is not detecting hardware changes with the video card. My most recent attempt at fixing it was to re-enable the onboard video with my motherboard, pull the Radeon card and see if it detected any hardware changes and did something different. It did not. Doing that made absolutely no difference at all. So why is it not detecting any changes in the video hardware and how can that be corrected? Or is that something that is too integral to Ubuntu to fix short of a fresh re-install?

**Originally**: 
Let me start of by saying that this is not a "why is there no fglrx?" type of post. I've been using Ubuntu since 2011. While I'm not new to it, I don't live and breathe the ins and outs of the innards of it either. I do love my Ubuntu though. I prefer it over loading the dreaded Windows. That said, I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.1 from 14.04 and I've been waiting for this for a while.... Saw that 16.04.1 was finally out and even though the updater wasn't offering it, triggered the upgrade. I saw that it said that the FGLRX drivers were depreciated, but that the AMDGPU drivers worked with my Radeon R9 380 card. Okay... cool. Went with the upgrade. Upgrade went pretty smoothly. Rebooted. Got into the login and beyond but my second monitor doesn't display anything. Kinda expected that. Went into Displays. It doesn't detect a secondary display. And it won't let me pick any other resolutions just a default 1366:768 (16:9) resolution. Poked around some and saw that supposedly the AMDGPU-PRO driver is supposed to be better. Alright. Went and installed that. Still the same situation. No secondary display and no additional resolutions. There are no config files in the /etc/x11/ directory. There is /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/01-amdgpu-pro.conf but what changes to it I need to make, I'm unsure. Please help.

I don't game from my system. I do some 3D modeling, but that's in Windows when I have to. I just want to be able to use the second monitor like I always do since that's how my workflow is most comfortable for me. (Primary focus on the big screen, secondary screen for IMs, email, reference materials, etc)

I'm competent enough to follow directions easily enough. One could say I know enough to be dangerous in linux. lol I'd really appreciate some help getting this resolved. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit 1# ** --  Was getting help from Reddit, but a moderator killed that. Anyways... Here's what I've done and where I'm at: 
lsmod shows neither radeon nor amdgpu (I manually looked and grepped for both)

`Storm-Linux:~$ sudo xrandr xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen 0: minimum 1366 x 768, current 1366 x 768, maximum 1366 x 768 default connected primary 1366x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm 1366x768 76.00*`

I also uninstalled AMDPro, rebooted, saw that nothing changed in Displays (no change to resolutions, no additional monitors). Reinstalled the AMDPro drivers and rebooted again. Still no change to the Displays dialogue screen. Right now I'd just be happy to see a change in the screen resolution... Still want my dual displays, but I think the screen resolution and the dual displays issue are part of the same problem.

**Edit #2** --
Burned and booted off of the Live CD for 16.04.1

lsmod shows that AMDGPU works fine there.

`amdkfd                131072  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
amdgpu                987136  6
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
ttm                    94208  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        147456  1 amdgpu`

And for comparisons, here is a screenshot of my installed system vs the Live CD's Displays dialogue... there is obviously something wrong going on here.

This is a screenshot of the Displays dialogue where things are not right.
[image: Malfunctioning desktop Displays screen]

This is a screenshot of the Live CD Displays dialogue where things are working correctly.
[image: Working Live CD Displays screen]

Obviously the problem is software, not hardware. And since this is Linux I should be able to fix it without having to reload Ubuntu and install all my apps from scratch again.

**Edit #3**:

I've uninstalled AMDPro and rebooted. No change in system behavior of course. I've copied the /var/log/Xorg.0.log to http://paste.ubuntu.com/21205770/

I notice that it tries to load the driver and then immediately after that it says:

```
[    30.603] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    30.603] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    30.603] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    30.613] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    30.613] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    30.613] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    30.613] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    30.613] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    30.613] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    30.646] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    30.646]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 0.0.2
[    30.646]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    30.646] (**) FBDEV(1): claimed PCI slot 1@0:0:0
[    30.646] (II) FBDEV(1): using default device
[    30.646] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    30.646] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    30.646] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    30.646] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section   "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    30.646] (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    30.646] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
[    30.646] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    30.646] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    30.646] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: VESA VGA (video memory: 4224kB)
[    30.646] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[    30.646] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[    30.646] (--) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 1366x768 (pitch 1366)
[    30.646] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current": 104.9 MHz, 60.5 kHz, 76.4 Hz
[    30.646] (II) FBDEV(0): Modeline "current"x0.0  104.92  1366 1398 1566 1734  768 772 776 792 -hsync -vsync -csync (60.5 kHz b)
[    30.646] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    30.646] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    30.646] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    30.646] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    30.662] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    30.662]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.0.0   
[    30.662]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    30.662] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[    30.662] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[    30.662] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[    30.662] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[    30.662] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    30.662]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.1.0
[    30.662]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    30.662] (II) UnloadModule: "radeon"
[    30.662] (II) Unloading radeon
[    30.662] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    30.662] (II) Unloading vesa
[    30.662] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    30.662] (II) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument (Screen blanking not supported by kernel - disabling)
[    30.706] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
[    30.707] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[    30.707] (==) RandR enabled
[    30.711] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
```

Most of that seems pertinent to this issue.Particularly the fact that it unloads the radeon drivers... The question is why is it doing that and how do we fix it?

Comment: I have to reinstall when I change hardware. There is a process of typing in a few dozen lines of text in the console but if fairly clueless just wipe and start again is easier to remember

Answer (score -1):

After over 48 hours of this issue and zero assistance from the 120+ pairs of eyes that have looked at this "question" since focusing my efforts entirely here I've thrown my hands in the air and just reinstalled Ubuntu from scratch. If you happen to encounter the same issue, I wish you better luck with support from others that know more than I have gotten.